# Can we push data to Openremote

Tags: http, queue, mqtt, iot, agent

I was recently exploring OpenRemote. I have created a basic HTTP agent for my API.
But I was wondering if Openremote provides any API on its own that can help me push data to OpenRemote rather than creating a HTTP Agent or Mqtt agent which pull data from my from API or mqtt client.

Can there is possibility that we could push data to any queue and then openremote gets updated.